# am335x and switching mode of GPIO3 under Linux

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

I'm trying to switch function mode of GPIO3 pin17 under Linux working on am335x. Linux starts with this GPIO3 configured as mode 4 (ecap pwm), but in some circumstances I'd like to switch this pin (17) to mode 7 (gpio mode). Here is snippet from my code:

```
// switch mode to 7
off = 0x800 + 0x19c;
val = *(x + off);
*(x + off) = (PIN_OUTPUT | MUX_MODE7);
val = *(x + off);

// 17-th pin must be output - clear it
gv1 = *(gpio + GPIO_OE);
gv2 = (gv1 & ~(1 << 17));
*(gpio + GPIO_OE) = gv2;

// set 17th bit in gpio3
gv2 = (1 << 17);
*(gpio + GPIO_DATAOUT) = gv2;
gv3 = *(gpio + GPIO_DATAOUT);
```

x and gpio are pointers achieved via ioremap_nocache() to proper address areas: 0x44e10000 (control module) and 0x481ae000 (gpio3).

The problem is that this code is not working. I mean there is LCD backlight connected to GPIO3 PIN17 which is controlled by ECAP PWM function (mode 4 from the SoC point of view). When I control this GPIO3_17 pin from userspace via "echo .." it is working fine (backlight is changing properly), but I'd like to switch sometimes ECAP PWM mode to GPIO and set the GPIO3_17 output to logical 1 - to achieve full power of backlight.

When I try to debug it I got for almost all the GPIO3 registers 0 value, but there is one exception - GPIO3_REVISION register. It is returning proper value: 0x50600801.

My question is - what can be the reason that this GPIO3 module returns proper value for GPIO3_REVISION register but all other registers are 0 and GPIO3 ignores everything I sent to other GPIO3 registers?

Any ideas? How to fix it?

Comment: What you're trying to do is misguided and simply wrong. Once a driver acquires a pin for its functionality, your code should not be interfering with that pin.  And your code encroaches on the functionality of the pin-control subsystem.

Comment: I know that I shouldn't do it by directly accessing registers and I should use the pin control subsystem, but I'm not sure if pin control subsys is designed for such a changes. Is the pinctrl providing any methods for changing functional mode for given GPIO?

Comment: @user2699113, partially. In most cases you just simple write/modify a driver which needs a pin in question. Harder cases require much more code and intrusion into the pin control subsystem itself.

Comment: @user2699113 *"Is the pinctrl providing any methods for changing functional mode for given GPIO?"* -- Not for what you're trying to do.  A pin is a resource that is managed, just like memory buffers.  When memory is allocated as a buffer for a process to use, you shouldn't be writing code to also use that buffer.  Nor should you expect the memory allocator to let you "borrow" that memory.  IOW you're expecting pincntrl to revoke an allocation without the owner's permission.  Resource allocation simply doesn't work that way.